# Why does Python's filecmp report files with different modified time as same when in shallow mode?

Tags: python, file, comparison

According to documentation I expect that if two files with different modification timestamps filecmp treats them as different. This is corroborated by the answer of [When will filecmp.cmp() return a false positive or false negative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46537057/when-will-filecmp-cmp-return-a-false-positive-or-false-negative).

However I observed different behavior.

Environment: Python 3.5 on Windows 10

Setting: prepared two directories with five corresponding files:

- Three pairs of files with identical content, two of them with different modification timestamp
- Two pairs with different content, one of them with identical length and identical modification timestamp (files "gleichalt_verschieden.txt", see below).

Experiment: run `filecmp.cmp_files` on the directories, run `filecmp.cmp` on each of the pairs and evaluate `filecmp._sig`:

```
filecmp.clear_cache()
dc = filecmp.dircmp(os.path.join(quelle, 'aenderungen_kopieren\\Dateien'), \
                   os.path.join(ziel, 'aenderungen_kopieren\\Dateien'))

flag_shallow = True
(mapping, not_mapping, _) = filecmp.cmpfiles(dc.left, dc.right, dc.common_files, flag_shallow)

print('flag_shallow: ', flag_shallow)
for (list, tl) in ((mapping, 'mapping'), (not_mapping, 'not_mapping')):
    print(tl, '--------------------------------------------')
    for l in list:
        links  = os.path.join(dc.left, l)
        rechts = os.path.join(dc.right, l)
        print(l)
        print('\t',filecmp._sig(os.stat(links)), '\n\t', filecmp._sig(os.stat(rechts)))
        print('_sig: ', filecmp._sig(os.stat(links)) == filecmp._sig(os.stat(rechts)), \
              '\tcmp: ', filecmp.cmp(links, rechts, shallow=flag_shallow), '\n')
```

Result:

```
flag_shallow:  True
mapping --------------------------------------------
neuer.txt
     (32768, 6, 1583743832.8992507) 
     (32768, 6, 1583692574.365337)
_sig:  False    cmp:  True 

gleichalt_verschieden.txt
     (32768, 8, 1583692574.365337) 
     (32768, 8, 1583692574.365337)
_sig:  True     cmp:  True 

gleich.txt
     (32768, 6, 1583692574.365337) 
     (32768, 6, 1583692574.365337)
_sig:  True     cmp:  True 

aelter.txt
     (32768, 6, 1583692574.365337) 
     (32768, 6, 1583743875.4433577)
_sig:  False    cmp:  True 

not_mapping --------------------------------------------
verschieden.txt
     (32768, 7, 1583692574.365337) 
     (32768, 6, 1583692574.365337)
_sig:  False    cmp:  False
```

Question:
Why does `filecmp.cmp` consider the pairs "neuer.txt" and "aelter.txt" as same although the modification timestamps are different and `filecmp._sig` detects this difference?

Answer (score 1):

> According to documentation I expect that if two files with different modification timestamps filecmp treats them as different

That makes no sense. The documentation explicitly says that if `shallow` is set and stat() is identical the files are considered the same **otherwise the contents of the files are compared**.

It doesn't say that the files are considered different if `stat` is different, in that case it would essentially never match.

`shallow` is a way to get a faster answer with a risk of false positives: if you have two files with different content but the exact same size and mtime they'll be considered identical despite not being so.

Comment: but shouldn't be stat() different if mtime is different (as in the two files mentioned above)? And the results from filecmp._sig are different.

Comment: Yes stat is different but again stat is a shortcut *to considering the file similar*. If stat is different then it always falls back to a "full" comparison of the files (though there's an obvious shortcut on length as files of different lengths can't be identical).

Answer (score -1):

From the source I understand that only the size, but not mtime is evaluated for a difference:

```
def cmp(f1, f2, shallow=True):
    ....
    if s1[0] != stat.S_IFREG or s2[0] != stat.S_IFREG:
        return False
    if shallow and s1 == s2:
        return True
    if s1[1] != s2[1]:
        return False
   ....
```

Therefore I find the documentation misleading:
"If shallow is true, files with identical os.stat() signatures are taken to be equal. Otherwise, the contents of the files are compared"

It should read:
"If shallow is true, files with identical os.stat() signatures are taken to be equal, files with different size are taken to be different. Otherwise, the contents of the files are compared"

Comment: You missed that `s1 = _sig(os.stat(f1))` and then `_sig()` is using mode, size and time, see https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/75c1ca7b6c546ef674eb40bfe47f41e6045dc99b/Lib/filecmp.py#L68